# How to use sprintf to pushback another string in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I need to pushback/ append another couple of strings with a given trailing pattern to an existing char array in C.
To achieve that, i'm willing to use 'sprintf' as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char my_str[1024]; // fixed length checked
    char *s1 = "abcd", *s2 = "pqrs";

    sprintf(my_str, "Hello World"); // begin part added
    sprintf(my_str, "%s , push back '%s' and '%s'.", my_str, s1, s2); // adding more to end of "my_str" (with given trailling format)
    /* here we always use 'my_str' as the first for the string format in sprintf - format starts with it */
    return 0;
}
```

I receive "memory overlapping" warning when i follow this method. is it be a serious issue? (like a memory leak, wrong output, etc.)

Comment: One option is to use [`strcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) instead.

Comment: You can't use the same string as both input and output in `sprintf()`.

Comment: Also, note that C and C++ are different languages and only the relevant tag should be used. Quite often the best answer is different depending on whether it is C or C++.

Comment: `char *s1 = "abcd\0", *s2 = "pqrs\0";`

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica String literals get a trailing null automatically, you don't need to put it explicitly.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.6 The sprintf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.6) "... If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: my point is, when the format string is starting with '%s' (eg : "%s<anything>"), it seems to be ok to add the same string for input and output. (because, after i adding "printf("%s", my_str);" i receive the correct output "Hello World , push back 'abcd' and 'pqrs'." in 'onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not allowed to use the same string for input and output when calling `sprintf()`

So, replace this:

```
sprintf(my_str, "%s , push back '%s' and '%s'.", my_str, s1, s2);
```

with this:

```
sprintf(my_str + strlen(my_str), " , push back '%s' and '%s'.", s1, s2);
```

Comment: my point is,

  when the format string is starting with '%s' (eg : "%s<anything>"), it seems to be ok to add the same string for input and output.

(because, after i adding "printf("%s", my_str);" i receive the correct output "Hello World , push back 'abcd' and 'pqrs'." in 'https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler')

Comment: @yasaramalshan — the trouble with undefined behaviour is that it can seem to work as you expected (even if your expectations are unfounded), but it can work differently at any time, and there's nothing you can do except fix your code because you broke the constraints on how you can safely use `sprintf()`.  Don't rely on undefined behaviour that happens to work at the moment on your machine; it may not work ever again.

Comment: The solution shown here eliminates the overlap and should be fine.  However, I would suggest using snprintf and possibly keeping track of the string length as you add to it (snprintf returns the number of characters printed) so that you can just use something like (buffer_size - total_printed) for the size argument and avoid a buffer overrun.  You can also use that value to avoid unnecessarily calling strlen().

Answer (score 2):

The warning is because you're not allowed to use the same string for both the output of `sprintf()` and one of the input arguments. The [specification](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.6p2) says:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Use a new string for the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char my_str[1024], my_str2[1024]; // fixed length checked
    char *s1 = "abcd", *s2 = "pqrs";

    sprintf(my_str, "Hello World"); // begin part added
    sprintf(my_str2, "%s , push back '%s' and '%s'.", my_str, s1, s2); // adding more to end of "my_str" (with given trailling format)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my point is, when the format string is starting with '%s' (eg : "%s<anything>"), it seems to be ok to add the same string for input and output. (because, after i adding "printf("%s", my_str);" i receive the correct output "Hello World , push back 'abcd' and 'pqrs'." in 'onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler')

Comment: I've added the quote from the specification that says it's not allowed. Just because it worked when you tried it, it doesn't mean it's generally OK.